# Extract the first word before a space using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

Let's say I have a column in my `users` table called `name`:

```
name
----
Brian
Jill Johnson
Sarah
Steven Smith
```

I want to write a PostgreSQL query to fetch just the first name. This is what I have so far:

```
select substr(name, 0, position(' ' IN name) | length(name) + 1) as first_name from users;
```

```
name
----
Brian
Jill
Sarah
Steven
```

This appears to work but I feel like there much be an easier way.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Question updated. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't follow the logic, your code looks like Postgres.  If so, use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
select split_part(name, ' ', 1)
from users;
```